# Unexpected behavior of LINQ Except()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I have encountered a strange bahavior of LINQ Except method which I don't understand. I can totally rewrite my code differently so that it works, that is not my problem. I just want to understand why it fails as it is:

```
public void MyMethod(MyClass whatever, params object[] values){ // called with values = [ "mystr1", "mystr2", true, true ] 
  var valuesOfType = values.OfType<MyType>().ToList(); // valuesOfType is Empty List Count = 0
  values = values.Except(valuesOfType ).ToArray(); // values = [ "mystr1", "mystr2", true ] 
}
```

So last element of `values` is gone by applying Except() with an empty list! How is this possible?
I reran in debugger immidiate window the line again, it was not trunkated to 2 elements. Self assignment to `values` is not a problem, I tried it with another variable, it still trunkates. What is happening here?

PS:
`MyType` is just a simple type with one get property.

Although the question is already answered, here is a reproduceable console app, if somebody should want to see it for himself:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var para = new object[] {"str1", "str2", true, true};
            var temp = new TestClass(new Dummy1(), para);
        }

        public class TestClass
        {
            public TestClass(Dummy1 dummy1, params object[] values)
            {
                var valuesOfType = values.OfType<Dummy2>().ToList();
                values = values.Except(valuesOfType).ToArray();

                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                }
                
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public class Dummy1
        {
        }

        public class Dummy2
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because LINQ `Except` produces a **set** difference, so duplicates are removed. From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0):

> This method returns those elements in first that don't appear in
> second. It doesn't return those elements in second that don't appear
> in first. **Only unique elements are returned.**

In your case you have two `true` values, so only one is returned.

Comment: That means `list.Except(emptylist)` is equal to `list.Distinct()`?

Comment: Basically yes. It's implementation first creates a set with elements from first sequence, then excludes elements from second, if any. If there are none - it just creates a set from first sequence

Comment: wow, thanks! that totally explains it. read the docs, as they say..